# How do I add a border under each navigation link without making the bottom border more bold

Tags: html, css

I can't seem to make the bottom border under LinkedIn link less bold as it is double bordered.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: #000000;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}

li:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
  <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/derrickogole">LinkedIn</a></li>
</ul>
```

[image]

Comment: If you say that the last `li` should not have a border, then `border-bottom: 1px solid;` should be on the `li`, not on the `a`.

Comment: `ul{border-bottom: none;}`

Comment: Just need a small update - `li:last-child a{
  border-bottom: none;
}`

Comment: Do you have ``* { border-collapse: collapse; }`` set in the style?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change css

```
li:last-child a {
  border-bottom: none; 
}
```

Comment: That worked. It was very simple. I only started coding last week.

Answer (score 3):

When you do that :

```
li a {
      border-bottom: 1px solid;
    }
```

you tell CSS to add a border bottom to all link inside a li.

```
li:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

was almost correct, but you didn't tell css the same rule as the previous snippet.

the good way to put this is

```
li:last-child a {
  border-bottom: none; 
}
```

Another thing you can remove

```
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
```

inside the ul block it does not do anything

Comment: Thanks for the help Greco. I am literally a beginner with HTML and CSS. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Here are my solution with extra class:

```
.liBorder {
  border-bottom: solid black 1px;
}

<ul>
  <li class="liBorder"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
  <li class="liBorder"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
  <li class="liBorder"><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
  <li class="liBorder"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  <li class="liBorder"><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/derrickogole">LinkedIn</a></li>
</ul>

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: #000000;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}

li:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

.liBorder {
  border-bottom: solid black 1px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/master1991/cjzfdg3v/3/

Comment: It's okay. I am literally a beginner with HTML and CSS so I will play around with your modifications even though it serves no purpose. LOOL!

Answer (score 0):

you can use this css

```
li:last-child a {
  border-bottom: none; 
}
li:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}
```